# Getting DataViolationIntegrityException while saving object using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations, nullable

I am using Hibernate as ORM mapping and MySQL as backend server.

```
public class Child{


  @NonNegative
  @Column(name = "height", nullable = false)
  private Double height;

  setter//

  public Double getHeight(){

     return (height!=null)?height:0.0;

  } 

}
```

So when I make save call I get DataViolationIntegrityException. I am sending null height from Client, but the getter method converts it into 0.0; Then why I am getting that Exception.

```
  session.save(child);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you use a double instead of a Double if it's not nullable?

Comment: I can use that will make my solution. But in project this pojo class is create firstly and changing it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**DataViolationIntegrityException** arises if we are violating any thing/constraint on Entity or Domain class while performing CRUD operations on Entity.

In above case nullable=false and I am trying to save null hence either convert 0.0 instead of null or change the return type to double instead of Double.